# Does Scala AnyRef.clone perform a shallow or deep copy?

Tags: scala, clone

In Scala, does `AnyRef.clone` perform a shallow or deep copy?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**Short answer**: shallow.

**Not-so-short answer**:
Unless it's overridden, AnyRef.clone() uses the Java's Object.clone() as its implementation.

Javadoc on Object.clone():

> The method clone for class Object
>   performs a specific cloning operation.
>   First, if the class of this object
>   does not implement the interface
>   Cloneable, then a
>   CloneNotSupportedException is thrown.
>   Note that all arrays are considered to
>   implement the interface Cloneable.
>   Otherwise, this method creates a new
>   instance of the class of this object
>   and initializes all its fields with
>   exactly the contents of the
>   corresponding fields of this object,
>   as if by assignment; the contents of
>   the fields are not themselves cloned.
>   Thus, this method performs a "shallow
>   copy" of this object, not a "deep
>   copy" operation.

Please note:

1. AnyRef.clone(), like its counterpart in Java, has a "protected" access level, so its **not** callable from everywhere.
2. You will need to implement Cloneable in order for clone() to work.

**Long answer**: Read *Effective Java, 2nd Edition, Item 11: Override clone judiciously*

**Summary**: Don't use it.  There are better alternatives.

Comment: "There are better alternatives."  Would you mind referencing some?

Comment: 1. Copy constructor, per C++.
2. Case class with built-in "copy" method in Scala 2.8.x.
3. Use immutable objects: no need to copy, just share.

Comment: So C++ -like copy constructors are actually (kind of) okay in Scala? I came to the language from C++ and before doing my first copy constructors wanted to see if I'm missing some point. Seems... it's fine (my objects have mutable state).