# How to copy a list in Scala

Tags: list, scala, copy, shallow-copy

I want to shallow copy a list in Scala.

I wanted to do somehing like:

```
val myList = List("foo", "bar")
val myListCopy = myList.clone
```

But the clone method is protected.

Comment: Wouldn't that be related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1267261/does-scala-anyref-clone-perform-a-shallow-or-deep-copy ?

Comment: What for? List objects are immutable.

Comment: I wanted to remove an element from the list (using remove(A=>Boolean) method) in a loop.

(Note: I started Scala 2 hours ago :))

Comment: When calling `myList.remove(s => s startsWith "f")`, a new list is created where `foo` is removed. `myList` remains *intact*. Lists are immutable in Scala by default, as Alexander Azarov already said.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To filter a list:

```
val list = List(1,2,3,4,5)
//only evens
val evens = list.filter(e=>e%2 == 0)

println(list)
//--> List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

println(evens) 
//--> List(2, 4)
```

You can also use the wildcard to save a few characters:

```
val evens = list.filter(_%2==0)
```

Note that, as commented above, lists are immutable.  That means that these operations do not modify the original list, but actually create a new list.

Comment: The user requested a way to copy a list (a list of Strings I suppose, according to the example) and your answer is to create a new list that filters the odd elements of an Integer list. Why was this response accepted as the best answer? I'm missing something?

Comment: How is your answer to filter a list related when the question asks for clone?

Answer (score 20):

Here's a non-answer: don't do that. A `List` is immutable, so there's absolutely no point in copying one.

Let's consider a few operations:

```
val list = List(1,2,3)
val l1 = 0 :: list
val l2 = "a" :: list
```

Neither `l1` nor `l2` are altering `list`, but they both create new lists that reference `list`.

Let's explain this in detail. The constructor `List(1,2,3)` is creating three elements, and using a singleton object as well. Specifically, it is instantiating these elements:

```
::(3, Nil)
::(2, reference to the previous element)
::(1, reference to the previous element)
```

And `Nil` is a singleton object. What the identifier `list` actually points to is that last element.

Now, when you assign `0 :: list` to `l1`, you are instantiating one new object:

```
::(0, reference to ::(1, etc))
```

Of course, since there's a reference to `list`, you can think of `l1` as a list of four elements (or five, if you count `Nil`).

Now `l2` isn't even of the same type of `list`, but it ALSO references it! Here:

```
::("a", reference to ::(1, etc))
```

The important point about all these objects, though, is that they can't be changed. There are no setters, nor any methods that will change any of their properties. They'll be forever having the same values/reference in their "head" (that's what we call the first element), and the same references in their "tail" (that's what we call the second element).

However, there are methods that *look* like their are changing the list. Rest assured, however, that they are creating *new* lists. For instance:

```
val l3 = list map (n => n + 1)
```

The method map creates a completely new list, of the same size, where new element may be computed from a corresponding element in `list` (but you might ignore the old element as well).

```
val l4 = l2 filter (n => n.isInstanceOf[Int])
```

While `l4` has the same elements as `list` (but a different type), it is also a completely new list. The method `filter` creates a new list, based on a rule you pass to tell it what elements go in and what don't. It doesn't try to optimize in case it *could* return an existing list.

```
val l5 = list.tail
```

This does not create a new list. Instead, it simply assigns to `l5` an existing element of `list`.

```
val l6 = list drop 2
```

Again, no new list created.

```
val l7 = list take 1
```

This, however, creates a new list, precisely because it can't change the first element of `list` so that its tail points to `Nil`.

Here's a few additional implementation details:

- `List` is an abstract class. It has two descendants, the class `::` (yes, that's the name of the class), and the singleton object `Nil`. `List` is sealed, so you can't add new subclasses to it, and `::` is final, so you can't subclass it.
- While you can't do anything to change a list, it uses mutable state internally in some operations. This helps with performance, but it is localized so that no program you write can ever detect it, or suffer consequences from it. You can pass lists around as you wish, no matter what the other functions do with them, or how many threads are using them concurrently.

Answer (score 0):

Use **:_*** type annotation

```
scala> val l1 = List(1,2,3)
l1: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)

scala> val l2 = List(l1:_*)
l2: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)
```

More details regarding annotation: [Scala: Constructor taking either Seq or varargs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7040382/scala-constructor-taking-either-seq-or-varargs)