# Scala: Constructor taking either Seq or varargs

Tags: scala, types, constructor, variadic-functions

I am guessing that, for compatibility reasons, the type of vararg parameters `Any*` is Array[Any] - please correct this if I'm wrong. However, this does not explain the following error:

```
class Api(api_url: String, params: Seq[(String, String)]) {
  def this(api_url: String, params: (String, String)*)
    = this(api_url, params.seq)
}
```

This code does not compile, but gives the warning:

> double definition: 
>   constructor Api:(api_url: String, params: (String, String)*)Api and constructor Api:(api_url: String, params:
>   Seq[(String, String)])Api at line 13 have same type after erasure:
>   (api_url: java.lang.String, params: Seq)Api

So how do I define a constructor taking either varargs or a sequence?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

A method taking varargs is also always taking a sequence, so there is no need to define an auxiliary constructor or overloaded method.

Given

```
class Api(api_url: String, params: (String, String)*)
```

you can call it like this

```
new Api("url", ("a", "b"), ("c", "d"))
```

or

```
val seq = Seq(("a", "b"), ("c", "d"))
new Api("url", seq:_*)
```

Also, in your question, you are calling method seq on the params parameter. This probably does not do what you intended. seq is used to ensure that operations on the resulting collection are executed sequentially instead of in parallel. The method was introduced with the parallel collections in version 2.9.0 of Scala.

What you probably wanted to use was toSeq, which returns the collection it is used on converted to a Seq (or itself if it is already a Seq). But as varargs parameters are already typed as Seq, that is a no-op anyway.

Comment: May I point out that the type annotation `:_*` is what really makes the constructor call using the sequence argument compatible to the varargs constructor. More details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6051302/what-does-colon-underscore-star-do-in-scala

Answer (score 10):

No: actually, `Any*` is actually almost identical to `Seq[Any]`, not to `Array[Any]`.

To disambiguate between the two, you can use the technique to add a dummy implicit parameter to make the signature different:

```
class Api(api_url: String, params: Seq[(String, String)]) {
  def this(api_url: String, params: (String, String)*)(implicit d: DummyImplicit) =
    this(api_url, params)
}
```

Comment: ...isn't this ...really disgusting?

Comment: Well, feel free to provide a less “disgusting” solution!

Comment: When I figure one out, I will. For now, I'll just scratch the `varargs` constructor. ^^

Comment: Why not keep the varargs constructor and let the caller do the `seq:_*` thing if he wants?

Comment: @Derek: because I didn't know `seq:_*` existed. :)

Comment: Designing new interfaces should one prefer `vargargs` over `Seq`?

Answer (score 2):

I suppose that you would like to make the method calls prettier and so explicit calling with `_*` is not an option. In that case you may solve the problem with method overloading.

```
class Api(api_url: String, params: Seq[(String, String)]) {
  def this(api_url: String, param : (String, String), params: (String, String)*)
    = this(api_url, param +: params)
  def this(api_url: String)
    = this(api_url, Seq())
}
```

Comment: This is the best solution as far as I'm concerned. It allows you to do 
`Api("url")`, `Api("url", "a" -> "b")`, `Api("url", Seq("a" -> "b"))` without sacrifiycing readability with the `:_*`