# Can immutable be a memory hog?

Tags: memory, functional-programming, immutability

Let's say we have a memory-intensive class like an `Image`, with chainable methods like `Resize()` and `ConvertTo()`.

If this class is immutable, won't it take a huge amount of memory when I start doing things like `i.Resize(500, 800).Rotate(90).ConvertTo(Gif)`, compared to a mutable one which modifies itself? How to handle a situation like this in a functional language?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

> If  this class is immutable, won't it take a huge amount of memory?

Typically your memory requirements *for that single object* might double, because you might have an "old copy" and a "new copy" live at once.  So you can view this phenomenon, over the lifetime of the program, as *having one more large object allocated* than you might in a typical imperative program.  (Objects that aren't being "worked on" just sit there, with the same memory requirements as in any other language.)

> How to handle a situation like this in a functional language?

**Do absolutely nothing.**  Or more accurately, allocate new objects in good health.
If you are using an implementation designed for functional programming, the allocator and garbage collector are almost certainly tuned for high allocation rates, and everything will be fine.  If you have the misfortune to try to run functional code on the JVM, well, performance won't be quite as good as with a bespoke implementation, but for most programs it will still be fine.

---

> Can you provide more detail?

Sure.  I'm going to take an exceptionally simple example: 1000x1000 greyscale image with 8 bits per pixel, rotated 180 degrees.  Here's what we know:

- To represent the image in memory requires 1MB.
- If the image is mutable, it's possible to rotate 180 degrees by doing an update in place.  The amount of temporary space needed is enough to hold one pixel.  You write a doubly nested loop that amounts to

  ```
  for (i in columns) do
    for (j in first half of rows) do {
       pixel temp := a[i, j]; 
       a[i, j] := a[width-i, height-j]; 
       a[width-i, height-j] := tmp
    }
  ```
- If the image is *immutable*, it's required to create an entire new image, and temporarily you have to hang onto the old image.  The code is something like this:

  ```
  new_a = Image.tabulate (width, height) (\ x y -> a[width-x, height-y])
  ```

  The `tabulate` function allocates an entire, immutable 2D array and initializes its contents.   During this operation, the old image is *temporarily* occupying memory.  But when `tabulate` completes, the old image `a` should no longer be used, and its memory is now free (which is to say, eligible for recycling by the garbage collector).  The amount of temporary space required, then, is enough to hold one image.
- While the rotation is going on, there's no need to have copies of objects of other classes; the temporary space is needed *only* for the image being rotated.

N.B. For other operations such as rescaling or rotating a  (non-square) image by 90 degrees, it is quite likely that even when images are mutable, a temporary copy of the entire image is going to be necessary, because the dimensions change.  On the other hand, colorspace transformations and other computations which are done pixel by pixel can be done using mutation with a very small temporary space.

Comment: I think even an object with mutable state will need both a source and destination buffer when mutating an image for most substantial transforms, especially things like `Resize()` and `Rotate()`.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure I understand the old copy, new copy thinking. Is it one more large object for every class returned by the chainable methods, or is it just one extra for the single object ("i" in this case). If you can elaborate a little, it's much appreciated.

Comment: How would you do a colorspace transform without a whole temporary image?

Comment: @gabe: If my image representation is mutable, such as a C union, I can convert RGB to Y/PB/PR by updating pixels in place.  I don't think it's a good idea, mind you...

Comment: Sorry, I thought you meant an immutable colorspace conversion could be done without making a new copy of the image. The problem with making temporary copies is that it puts pressure on your cache and blows up your workingset. And then your garbage collector has to either do tons of copying or deal with fragmentation.

Comment: @gabe: Modern garbage collectors and memory allocators are very cache-aware.  New objects are allocated in an area called the *nursery*, which is always in the same location.  Only objects that survive a minor collection are copied, so "tons of copying" is not necessary.  The nursery is always in the same location and is contiguous, not fragmented, so allocation is extremely fast.  None of this is rocket science; such collectors have been deployed since 1995 and in wide use since 2000.  Some JVMs have been late to the party, but the solutions are known.

Comment: Generational copy collectors as you're describing are great for lots of small short-lived objects. But we're dealing with images here. Lots of digital cameras now are 20MP which, at 16 bits/channel, generate 120MB files. When you call `Image.tabulate(5600, 3600)` you are allocating a 120MB chunk of memory, making your process's working set 240MB. Is your heap's nursery going to hold 240MB? If so, it has to copy at least one 120MB image when it does a collection. If it goes directly into your tenured heap, that heap gets all fragmented.

Comment: @gabe: *nothing* is going to make processing huge images efficient---it's the canonical example my students work with to explore the limits of the hardware cache.  And this is working with mutable structures.  The rule of thumb in my original answer still holds: if the performance limit in your code is the size of a single  object, immutability *may* double your memory requirements, or it may not, depending on the image operation.  So worst case, you can deal with half the image you could with a mutable representation.  That's the cost.

Comment: My point exactly -- image processing is a canonical example of where mutability can make a big difference.

Comment: @Gabe: "If it goes directly into your tenured heap, that heap gets all fragmented". You're assuming the old generation is non-moving.

Comment: -1: You're assuming that the purely functional data structure used to represent an image is an array. If it were a more idiomatic balanced binary tree then the memory requirements would be huge in comparison. You're assuming the GC will collect unreachable images quickly but they are so large that they will rarely be collected and are likely to last for a long time. Your statements about caches are either wrong ("nothing is going to make processing huge images efficient") or irrelevant ("Modern garbage collectors and memory allocators are very cache-aware").

Comment: Just a side note for those who were a bit confused about the JVM part from this answer. Immutable objects in Java actually lead to decreased overheads due to GC. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/immutable.html

Answer (score 18):

Yes. Immutability is a component of the eternal time-space tradeoff in computing: you sacrifice memory in exchange for the increased processing speed you gain in parallelism by foregoing locks and other concurrent access control measures.

Functional languages typically handle operations of this nature by chunking them into very fine grains. Your Image class doesn't actually hold the logical data bits of the image; rather, it uses pointers or references to much smaller immutable data segments which contain the image data. When operations need to be performed on the image data, the smaller segments are cloned and mutated, and a new copy of the Image is returned with updated references -- most of which point to data which has not been copied or changed and has remained intact.

This is one reason why functional design requires a different fundamental thought process from imperative design. Not only are algorithms themselves laid out very differently, but data storage and structures need to be laid out differently as well to account for the memory overhead of copying.

Answer (score 3):

In some cases, immutability forces you to clone the object and needs to allocate more memory. It doesn't necessary *occupy* the memory, because older copies can be discarded. For example, the CLR garbage collector deals with this situation quite well, so this isn't (usually) a big deal.

However, chaining of operations doesn't actually mean cloning the object. This is certainly the case for functional lists. When you use them in the typical way, you only need to allocate a memory cell for a single element (when appending elements to the front of the list).

Your example with image processing can be also implemented in a more efficient way. I'll use C# syntax to keep the code easy to understand without knowing any FP (but it would look better in a usual functional language). Instead of actually cloning the image, you could just store the operations that you want to do with the image. For example something like this:

```
class Image { 
  Bitmap source;
  FileFormat format;
  float newWidth, newHeight;
  float rotation;

  // Public constructor to load the image from a file
  public Image(string sourceFile) { 
    this.source = Bitmap.FromFile(sourceFile); 
    this.newWidth = this.source.Width;
    this.newHeight = this.source.Height;
  }

  // Private constructor used by the 'cloning' methods
  private Image(Bitmap s, float w, float h, float r, FileFormat fmt) {
    source = s; newWidth = w; newHeight = h; 
    rotation = r; format = fmt;
  }

  // Methods that can be used for creating modified clones of
  // the 'Image' value using method chaining - these methods only
  // store operations that we need to do later
  public Image Rotate(float r) {
    return new Image(source, newWidth, newHeight, rotation + r, format);
  }
  public Image Resize(float w, float h) {
    return new Image(source, w, h, rotation, format);
  }
  public Image ConvertTo(FileFormat fmt) {
    return new Image(source, newWidth, newHeight, rotation, fmt);
  }

  public void SaveFile(string f) { 
    // process all the operations here and save the image
  }
}
```

The class doesn't actually create a clone of the entire bitmap each time you invoke a method. It only keeps track of what needs to be done later, when you'll finally try to save the image. In the following example, the underlying `Bitmap` would be created only once:

```
 var i = new Image("file.jpg");
 i.Resize(500, 800).Rotate(90).ConvertTo(Gif).SaveFile("fileNew.gif");
```

In summary, the code looks like you're cloning the object and you're actually creating a new copy of the `Image` class each time you call some operation. However, that doesn't mean that the operation is memory expensive - this can be hidden in the functional library, which can be implemented in all sorts of ways (but still preserv the important *referential transparency*).

Answer (score 1):

Yes one of the disadvantage of using immutable objects is that they tend to hog memory, One thing that comes to my mind is something similar to lazy evaluation, which is when a new copy is requested provide a reference and when the user does some changes then initialize the new copy of the object.

Comment: Tcl does something like this internally, except that it doesn't duplicate the object if only one reference to it is held. In that case, it is safe to update the object directly as the only thing that  can see the difference is the caller who is expecting the value to change.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the type of data structures used, their application in a given program.  In general, immutability does not have to be overly expensive on memory.

You may have noticed that the persistent data structures used in functional programs tend to eschew arrays.  This is because persistent data structures typically reuse most of their components when they are "modified".  (They are not really modified, of course.  A new data structure is returned, but the old one is just the same as it was.)  [See this picture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Purely_functional_tree_after.svg) to get an idea of how the structure sharing can work.  In general, tree structures are favoured, because a new immutable tree can be created out of an old immutable tree only rewriting the path from the root to the node in question.  Everything else can be reused, making the process efficient in both time and memory.

In regards to your example, there are several ways to solve the problem other than copying a whole massive array.  (That actually would be horribly inefficient.)  My preferred solution would be to use a tree of array chunks to represent the image, allowing for relatively little copying on updates.  Note an additional advantage: we can at relatively small cost store multiple versions of our data.

I don't mean to argue that immutability is always and everywhere the answer -- the truth and righteousness of functional programming should be tempered with pragmatism, after all.

Answer (score 0):

Short, tangential answer: in FP language I'm familiar with (scala, erlang, clojure, F#), and for the usual data structures: arrays, lists, vectors, tuples, you need to understand shallow/deep copies and how implemented:

e.g.

Scala, clone() object vs. copy constructor

[Does Scala AnyRef.clone perform a shallow or deep copy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1267261/does-scala-anyref-clone-perform-a-shallow-or-deep-copy)

Erlang: message passing a shallow-copied data structure can blow up a process:

http://groups.google.com/group/erlang-programming/msg/bb39d1a147f72800

Comment: Does not answer the question. Do you mean immutable libraries do shallow copy?