# Elements of original array still modified after cloning

Tags: scala

I have the following code:

```
val copyA = a.clone
copyA(0)(0) = 1
println("a(0)(0): " + a(0)(0))
```

This prints:

```
a(0)(0): 1
```

If I change it to this:

```
val copyA = a.clone
println("a(0)(0): " + a(0)(0))
```

It prints:

```
a(0)(0): 0
```

So why is `a` affected by a change in `copyA`?

How can I make it such that changes in `copyA` don't affect `a`?

Comment: your both cases are same `copyA(0)(0) = 1`, is that what you mean?

Comment: both of your code snippets are identical

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1267261/does-scala-anyref-clone-perform-a-shallow-or-deep-copy

Comment: Sorry, I updated it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does Scala AnyRef.clone perform a shallow or deep copy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1267261/does-scala-anyref-clone-perform-a-shallow-or-deep-copy)

Answer (score 3):

Mutating the cloned 1D array instance won't change the original instance and vice-versa,

example,

```
scala> val original = Array(100, 200)
original: Array[Int] = Array(100, 200)

scala> val cloned = original.clone
cloned: Array[Int] = Array(100, 200)
```

**mutating `cloned` array does not affect `original` array,**

```
scala> cloned(0) = 5000

scala> original(0) //still the same value
res36: Int = 100
```

**mutating `original` array does not affect `cloned` array,**

```
scala> original(0) = 8888

scala> cloned(0) // still the same
res38: Int = 5000
```

**But its different regarding 2D array, because each array inside is a ref and has to be deep cloned**

```
scala> val original = Array.ofDim[Int](2,2)
original: Array[Array[Int]] = Array(Array(0, 0), Array(0, 0))

scala> original.foreach {col => println(col)}
[I@745e24c4
[I@42c6563f
```

**deep cloning 2D array**

```
scala> val cloned = original.map(_.clone)
cloned: Array[Array[Int]] = Array(Array(0, 0), Array(0, 0))

scala> original(0)(0) = 5000

scala> cloned(0)(0)
res43: Int = 0

//changing cloned does not change original array 
scala> cloned(0)(0) = 8888

scala> original(0)(0)
res48: Int = 5000
```

Answer (score 2):

You cloned the array. You didn't clone whatever was *in* the array.

In your code, you are not manipulating the array. You are getting an element out of the array and manipulating *that object*. The arrays are completely irrelevant here.